# XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry() works fine through eclipse, but doesn't work in a third party app

Tags: java, android, xdocreport

I'm using **XDocReport** to replace the data in placeholders in docx file. This worked fine from eclipse. I exported the App Client Jar file and used it in another third party product. the **getRegistry** method threw exception with the message:

**fr/opensagres/xdocreport/document/registry/XDocReportRegistry**

Please help.

Comment: It seems that it's a problem with your classpath. Check you have the well XDocReport JARs in your classpath of your App Client.

Comment: You're right. I placed the jars in the 3rd party app server's common lib directory and it worked fine after restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

I placed the XDocReport JARs in the 3rd party app server's common lib directory and it worked fine after restarting the server.